# Method, Trigger for user login in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I was hoping that using Google Apps Script I could setup a trigger to run when I log into email - web browser, or phone, or anything. The trigger would run my script.

Does anyone know if there's a way to hack this?

Comment: Are there any updates on this question? I know it's an old question, but did you ever manage to do what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done exactly the way you want. But a circular route is this: have your script with a time trigger which keeps checking an unread email count in a custom folder(say test) (say every 5 mins). You can use the GmailApp/getUnreadCount() for this purpose. If there is an unread email, it'll clear it and run the required code.

no whenever you need to run the script, all you have to do is send an email to yourself, with the gmail address extension. eg: yourgmailid+test@gmail.com

In this way, the email will automatically have the label of "test" and will be unread, triggering your script the next cycle.